# Cakephp 2.x mobile theme and prefix

Tags: jquery-mobile, cakephp-2.1, prefix

I am currently adding a custom mobile layout for one of my apps.

AppController.php

```
if ($this->request->is('mobile')) {
   //$this->viewClass = 'Theme';
   $this->theme = 'Mobile';
} else {
   $this->theme = Configure::read('App.theme'); 
}
```

Working just fine.. Have jquery mobile running flawlessly now. 
However, I would like to develop on separate functions in the controllers, as the main website, does gather much more data from the DB than the mobile version will require.

So I am thinking of an approach like, if request mobile => set this prefix = mobile or something like that? To allow for separate mobile functions in the controller.

Any suggestions?

Also, I would like to set a param when page is loaded, like, Do you want to view the mobile version? Yes / No. If No => show mobile = false, if yes => show mobile = true. Preferably by some sort of popup (like the tapatalk forum app notification).

Thanks for any help with this.. :)

-Tom

Answer (score 0):

Just like you use *$this->request->is('mobile')* in your *AppController*, you can use the same  method in all of your controllers and do your logic depending on the request type, it is a good way of achieving your goal.

Secondly;

You can create an element asking user "Mobile or Not?".

In your landing page controller (or if you want to make this check in each page, eg. if user lands on a specific page with link from other sites. Then do this in *AppController beforeFilter()*) you check a value like:

```
$mobilePref = Configure::read('Config.mobilePreference');
if($mobilePref){
     $this->set('showMobileElement', true);
} else {
     if($mobilePref == 'Mobile'){
          $this->set('showMobileLayout', true);
     } else {
          $this->set('showMobileLayout', false);
     }
}
```

And in your layout, you simply check **$showMobileLayout**, if it is true you show the mobile layout, if false you show the normal layout.
If it is not set you check **$showMobilePref** and if it is true, you call the "Mobile or Not?" element. And depending the answer of user from element, you set

```
 Configure::write('Config.mobilePreference', true); //or false, depending on answer
```

That is roughly it, i suppose. Of course if you are authenticating users, you should save the choice of user and remember it next time user logs in.